# problems in read/write program with python

Tags: python, url-rewriting, addition

so I have an archive were there is a number, say 1, and I want to do a program that reads that 1, then add 1 so 1+1=2 and then print in the archive 2, so now there is only a 2 in the archive. What I did is this

```
outfile = open('text.txt', 'r')
m=outfile.readline()
g=m+1
outfile.close()
outfile = open('text.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(str(g))
outfile.close()
```

but it keeps saying:

```
TypeError: can't concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I know the error that I am doing... but I can't solve it. Mind helping me in this one? Thank you cleverer people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's what the 'error' is telling you.
You're trying to "add" a string with an integer.

When you read from file, you're reading text.
So you have to convert that text you're reading to an integer.

If you know exactly what you have in each line, you can just use a cast `g = int(m) +1`

Answer (score 1):

When you read `m`, it is a string. You need to cast it to `int` before adding 1.

```
with open("text.txt") as inf:
    m = inf.read()

g = int(m) + 1

with open("text.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(g))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had asked a similar question earlier adn had the SAME issue, you're trying to concatenate `strings` and `integers`.

change it to this -`g=int(m)+1`